# Sending to Kafka from a spark job taking too much time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job which consumes data from kafka and send back to kafka after doing some process on each data.
For this i am doing some map operations on data ,

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicNameMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
var ad = ""
val abc = lines.map(_._2).map { x =>
  val jsonObj = new JSONObject(x)
  val data = someMethod(schema, jsonObj)
  data
}
```

then i am doing foreach operation on it , i am not collecting all the data to driver here since i want to send those record inside the executor itself.

```
abc.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreach { toSend =>
    val producer = KafkaProducerUtils.getKafkaProducer(kafkaBrokers)
    println("toSend---->" + toSend)
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topicToSend, toSend))
  }
```

I tried this code for 1405 data for a 10 second period , but it took approximately 2.5 minute to complete the job. I know creating `KafkaProducer` is costly , Is there any other way around to reduce the processing time. For my testing purpose i am using 2 executors with 2 cores and 1GM each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot i found this article about [KafkaSink](http://allegro.tech/2015/08/spark-kafka-integration.html) . This will give you the idea about producing data to kafka inside spark streaming in effective way.

Answer (score 0):

There must be several reasons for this enormous delay processing this amount of messages:

1. The problem could reside in your consume phase. If you use "createStream", at least, minor versions of Spark use the high level consumer implementation which needs Zookeeper to storage the offset of the consumers which belong to a specific group. So I´d check  this communication because it could take too much time in the *commit* phase. If for any reason that makes commit for each one by one your consume rate could be impaired. So first of all, check this.
2. There is another reason due to the write ahead log to the file system. Although your configuration indicates memory an disk, as you can see in Spark documentation:

> Efficiency: Achieving zero-data loss in the first approach required the data to be stored in a Write Ahead Log, which further replicated the data. This is actually inefficient as the data effectively gets replicated twice - once by Kafka, and a second time by the Write Ahead Log. This second approach eliminates the problem as there is no receiver, and hence no need for Write Ahead Logs. As long as you have sufficient Kafka retention, messages can be recovered from Kafka

For better consume rates I would use createDirectStream instead.